# Duplicated files or mocks when trying to use Expo Go App

Tags: react-native, jestjs, compiler-errors, expo, sanity

Thank you for taking up sometimes to read this article and trying to help me to solve this problem.
I have this problem over and over and over for the last 14 days every time I try to open a project of mine using the expo Go App in my phone,
it works just fine in with the web version,

```
Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
at setModule (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:576:17)                                                             \build\index.js:576:17)    
at workerReply (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:647:9)   ap\build\index.js:647:9)
at async Promise.all (index 12)                                                 x.js:459:22
at C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\indenode-haste\DependencyGraph.x.js:459:22
at Function.load (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:61:5)node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:86:36)                                                \metro\src\IncrementalBundl
at Bundler.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:61:5)                                                                    erver.js:1156:5)
at IncrementalBundler.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:309:5)
at Server.ready (C:\Users\Slima\Desktop\deliveroo-clone\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1156:5)
```